# Steam API Array Output

Tags: php, curl, steam-web-api

What am I doing wrong? Foreach does not work.
The usual output of $ players works correctly, but when you try to climb directly into json, it just hangs without error.
Please explain to the fool (

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';  
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM rcc_logs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) sub ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysqli_error($link));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $players .= $row['player'] . ',';
    $json = "https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=MYKEYHERE&steamids=".$players."&format=json";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $json);
    $parsed = curl_exec($ch);
    $parsed = json_decode($parsed);
    echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$row['player'].'</td>';
        foreach($parsed->response->players as $player) {
            if (getimagesize($player->avatarmedium) !== false) {
                $img_source = $player->avatarmedium;
            } else {
                $img_source = '/lol/img/none.jpg';
            }
            echo '<td class="txt-oflo"><a target="_blank" href="'.$player->profileurl.'"><img src="'.$img_source.'" alt="user-img" style="width: 20px; margin-right: 10px; border-radius: 50px;">'.htmlspecialchars($player->personaname, ENT_QUOTES).'</a></td>';
        }
    '</tr>';        
}
mysqli_close($link);
curl_close($ch); ?>
```

Output

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [response] => stdClass Object ( 
        [players] => Array ( 
                [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                    [steamid] => 76561198085600898 
                    [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 
                    [profilestate] => 1 
                    [personaname] => [REICH]_v_o_l_t_ 
                    [lastlogoff] => 1534403067 
                    [commentpermission] => 1 
                    [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198085600898/ 
                    [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa.jpg 
                    [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa_medium.jpg 
                    [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa_full.jpg 
                    [personastate] => 1 
                    [realname] => Vlad 
                    [primaryclanid] => 103582791455391679 
                    [timecreated] => 1362665057 
                    [personastateflags] => 0 
                    [gameextrainfo] => Rust 
                    [gameid] => 252490 
                    [loccountrycode] => RU 
                    [locstatecode] => 47 
                    [loccityid] => 42052 
                ) 
        ) 
    ) 
) 
stdClass Object ( [response] => stdClass Object ( [players] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198324890789 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => Defense of the Autists [lastlogoff] => 1534374108 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198324890789/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300_full.jpg [personastate] => 3 [realname] => САША [primaryclanid] => 103582791455862953 [timecreated] => 1470677941 [personastateflags] => 0 [gameextrainfo] => Rust [gameid] => 252490 [loccountrycode] => US ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198085600898 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => [REICH]_v_o_l_t_ [lastlogoff] => 1534403067 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198085600898/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa_full.jpg [personastate] => 1 [realname] => Vlad [primaryclanid] => 103582791455391679 [timecreated] => 1362665057 [personastateflags] => 0 [gameextrainfo] => Rust [gameid] => 252490 [loccountrycode] => RU [locstatecode] => 47 [loccityid] => 42052 ) ) ) ) stdClass Object ( [response] => stdClass Object ( [players] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198800935154 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => Blackpro [lastlogoff] => 1534378165 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/id/mygame203/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b77087d1b109e6026589a5350c5da624df2d04a.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b77087d1b109e6026589a5350c5da624df2d04a_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b77087d1b109e6026589a5350c5da624df2d04a_full.jpg [personastate] => 1 [primaryclanid] => 103582791462034778 [timecreated] => 1514630300 [personastateflags] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198324890789 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => Defense of the Autists [lastlogoff] => 1534374108 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198324890789/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300_full.jpg [personastate] => 3 [realname] => САША [primaryclanid] => 103582791455862953 [timecreated] => 1470677941 [personastateflags] => 0 [gameextrainfo] => Rust [gameid] => 252490 [loccountrycode] => US ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198085600898 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => [REICH]_v_o_l_t_ [lastlogoff] => 1534403067 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198085600898/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa_full.jpg [personastate] => 1 [realname] => Vlad [primaryclanid] => 103582791455391679 [timecreated] => 1362665057 [personastateflags] => 0 [gameextrainfo] => Rust [gameid] => 252490 [loccountrycode] => RU [locstatecode] => 47 [loccityid] => 42052 ) ) ) ) stdClass Object ( [response] => stdClass Object ( [players] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198800935154 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => Blackpro [lastlogoff] => 1534378165 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/id/mygame203/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b77087d1b109e6026589a5350c5da624df2d04a.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b77087d1b109e6026589a5350c5da624df2d04a_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b77087d1b109e6026589a5350c5da624df2d04a_full.jpg [personastate] => 1 [primaryclanid] => 103582791462034778 [timecreated] => 1514630300 [personastateflags] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198311995151 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => blagin [lastlogoff] => 1534406030 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198311995151/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/6e/6e67aecfd2e7bceea7977c09aadcf8689a4d21bb.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/6e/6e67aecfd2e7bceea7977c09aadcf8689a4d21bb_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/6e/6e67aecfd2e7bceea7977c09aadcf8689a4d21bb_full.jpg [personastate] => 0 [primaryclanid] => 103582791455225665 [timecreated] => 1466253721 [personastateflags] => 0 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198324890789 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => Defense of the Autists [lastlogoff] => 1534374108 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198324890789/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300_full.jpg [personastate] => 3 [realname] => САША [primaryclanid] => 103582791455862953 [timecreated] => 1470677941 [personastateflags] => 0 [gameextrainfo] => Rust [gameid] => 252490 [loccountrycode] => US ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198085600898 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => [REICH]_v_o_l_t_ [lastlogoff] => 1534403067 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198085600898/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa_full.jpg [personastate] => 1 [realname] => Vlad [primaryclanid] => 103582791455391679 [timecreated] => 1362665057 [personastateflags] => 0 [gameextrainfo] => Rust [gameid] => 252490 [loccountrycode] => RU [locstatecode] => 47 [loccityid] => 42052 ) ) ) ) stdClass Object ( [response] => stdClass Object ( [players] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198311995151 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => blagin [lastlogoff] => 1534406030 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198311995151/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/6e/6e67aecfd2e7bceea7977c09aadcf8689a4d21bb.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/6e/6e67aecfd2e7bceea7977c09aadcf8689a4d21bb_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/6e/6e67aecfd2e7bceea7977c09aadcf8689a4d21bb_full.jpg [personastate] => 0 [primaryclanid] => 103582791455225665 [timecreated] => 1466253721 [personastateflags] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198800935154 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => Blackpro [lastlogoff] => 1534378165 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/id/mygame203/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b77087d1b109e6026589a5350c5da624df2d04a.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b77087d1b109e6026589a5350c5da624df2d04a_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b77087d1b109e6026589a5350c5da624df2d04a_full.jpg [personastate] => 1 [primaryclanid] => 103582791462034778 [timecreated] => 1514630300 [personastateflags] => 0 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198324890789 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => Defense of the Autists [lastlogoff] => 1534374108 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198324890789/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300_full.jpg [personastate] => 3 [realname] => САША [primaryclanid] => 103582791455862953 [timecreated] => 1470677941 [personastateflags] => 0 [gameextrainfo] => Rust [gameid] => 252490 [loccountrycode] => US ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198257826494 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => LowSkill [lastlogoff] => 1534376895 [commentpermission] => 2 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/id/ssada5451/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_full.jpg [personastate] => 0 [realname] => Каха [primaryclanid] => 103582791439388164 [timecreated] => 1446218860 [personastateflags] => 0 [loccountrycode] => RU ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198085600898 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => [REICH]_v_o_l_t_ [lastlogoff] => 1534403067 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198085600898/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa_full.jpg [personastate] => 1 [realname] => Vlad [primaryclanid] => 103582791455391679 [timecreated] => 1362665057 [personastateflags] => 0 [gameextrainfo] => Rust [gameid] => 252490 [loccountrycode] => RU [locstatecode] => 47 [loccityid] => 42052 ) ) ) ) stdClass Object ( [response] => stdClass Object ( [players] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198800935154 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => Blackpro [lastlogoff] => 1534378165 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/id/mygame203/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b77087d1b109e6026589a5350c5da624df2d04a.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b77087d1b109e6026589a5350c5da624df2d04a_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b77087d1b109e6026589a5350c5da624df2d04a_full.jpg [personastate] => 1 [primaryclanid] => 103582791462034778 [timecreated] => 1514630300 [personastateflags] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198257826494 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => LowSkill [lastlogoff] => 1534376895 [commentpermission] => 2 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/id/ssada5451/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_full.jpg [personastate] => 0 [realname] => Каха [primaryclanid] => 103582791439388164 [timecreated] => 1446218860 [personastateflags] => 0 [loccountrycode] => RU ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198257826494 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => LowSkill [lastlogoff] => 1534376895 [commentpermission] => 2 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/id/ssada5451/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_full.jpg [personastate] => 0 [realname] => Каха [primaryclanid] => 103582791439388164 [timecreated] => 1446218860 [personastateflags] => 0 [loccountrycode] => RU ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198311995151 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => blagin [lastlogoff] => 1534406030 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198311995151/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/6e/6e67aecfd2e7bceea7977c09aadcf8689a4d21bb.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/6e/6e67aecfd2e7bceea7977c09aadcf8689a4d21bb_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/6e/6e67aecfd2e7bceea7977c09aadcf8689a4d21bb_full.jpg [personastate] => 0 [primaryclanid] => 103582791455225665 [timecreated] => 1466253721 [personastateflags] => 0 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198085600898 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => [REICH]_v_o_l_t_ [lastlogoff] => 1534403067 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198085600898/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/8a/8a7a6bfaa3bd892174405c2d90beeacacf05a9fa_full.jpg [personastate] => 1 [realname] => Vlad [primaryclanid] => 103582791455391679 [timecreated] => 1362665057 [personastateflags] => 0 [gameextrainfo] => Rust [gameid] => 252490 [loccountrycode] => RU [locstatecode] => 47 [loccityid] => 42052 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198324890789 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => Defense of the Autists [lastlogoff] => 1534374108 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198324890789/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300_full.jpg [personastate] => 3 [realname] => САША [primaryclanid] => 103582791455862953 [timecreated] => 1470677941 [personastateflags] => 0 [gameextrainfo] => Rust [gameid] => 252490 [loccountrycode] => US ) ) ) ) stdClass Object ( [response] => stdClass Object ( [players] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198800935154 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => Blackpro [lastlogoff] => 1534378165 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/id/mygame203/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b77087d1b109e6026589a5350c5da624df2d04a.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b77087d1b109e6026589a5350c5da624df2d04a_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b77087d1b109e6026589a5350c5da624df2d04a_full.jpg [personastate] => 1 [primaryclanid] => 103582791462034778 [timecreated] => 1514630300 [personastateflags] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198324890789 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => Defense of the Autists [lastlogoff] => 1534374108 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198324890789/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/cc/cca75c6800387f6fbbb8f670c1d0f9acf3e1a300_full.jpg [personastate] => 3 [realname] => САША [primaryclanid] => 103582791455862953 [timecreated] => 1470677941 [personastateflags] => 0 [gameextrainfo] => Rust [gameid] => 252490 [loccountrycode] => US ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198257826494 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => LowSkill [lastlogoff] => 1534376895 [commentpermission] => 2 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/id/ssada5451/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_full.jpg [personastate] => 0 [realname] => Каха [primaryclanid] => 103582791439388164 [timecreated] => 1446218860 [personastateflags] => 0 [loccountrycode] => RU ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198257826494 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => LowSkill [lastlogoff] => 1534376895 [commentpermission] => 2 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/id/ssada5451/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_full.jpg [personastate] => 0 [realname] => Каха [primaryclanid] => 103582791439388164 [timecreated] => 1446218860 [personastateflags] => 0 [loccountrycode] => RU ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198421594792 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => zuza [lastlogoff] => 1534402527 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198421594792/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/b6/b60262610c4fd34dfb719b13109d8014b2feba15.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/b6/b60262610c4fd34dfb719b13109d8014b2feba15_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/b6/b60262610c4fd34dfb719b13109d8014b2feba15_full.jpg [personastate] => 0 [realname] => рома [primaryclanid] => 103582791461396682 [timecreated] => 1505320484 [personastateflags] => 0 [loccountrycode] => AD [locstatecode] => 03 [loccityid] => 5065 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [steamid] => 76561198311995151 [communityvisibilitystate] => 3 [profilestate] => 1 [personaname] => blagin [lastlogoff] => 1534406030 [commentpermission] => 1 [profileurl] => https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198311995151/ [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/6e/6e67aecfd2e7bceea7977c09aadcf8689a4d21bb.jpg [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/6e/6e67aecfd2e7bceea7977c09aadcf8689a4d21bb_medium.jpg [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/6e/6e67aecfd2e7bceea7977c09aadcf8689a4d21bb_full.jpg [personastate] => 0 [primaryclanid] => 103582791455225665 [timecreated] => 1466253721 [personastateflags] => 0 )
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is to output that `$parsed` variable and actually confirm the data is correct. As far as I can tell, the player stuff outputs because that's related to your data you have already, not because of steam's response

Comment: if i use print_r($parsed); everything is excellently displayed. But foreach itself does not want to output in the correct format. I have no idea what is wrong with him.

Comment: _Small Off Piste Question_ Why has that query been built with a sub query. Its a simple enough query and does not need a sub query unless you just like wasting CPU Cycles

Comment: @Ronohx Could you give us an example of what your json output from steam is like? (obviously remove any sensitive/identifying information)

Comment: Yes, as @IsThisJavascript suggests. echo out `$parsed` preferably before you try and json_decode it and check a) you got a reply and b) it is JSON

Comment: Added steam json output example.

Comment: Your code works for me given your example however, `getimagesize($player->avatarmedium) !== false` is breaking it. I switched that to just `$player->avatarmedium` and my output looks like what you wanted

Comment: Omg i change $players to $users and it works... What kind of conflict it seemed.

Comment: I dont really see why that would cause the issue as `$players` has nothing to do with `$parsed->response->players` but I'm happy to hear you managed to fix it

Comment: but there is a problem, when asked directly, the answer comes in 2 seconds. And through the code itself, a minute is loaded. In what trabbl?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `json_decode($parsed, true)` so you would get back a array by default  than do a **foreach** on `$parsed[response][players] => $players` that should work